# When I add a new source folder to c++ eclipse project how do I get the makefile updated?

Tags: eclipse, makefile, eclipse-cdt

I am new to using makefiles with C++.  I tried creating an eclipse(Juno) C++ exe project that had the option enable to auto-generate makefiles.  It seems to work fine as long as I only add files to the src folder but if I try to create a new source folder and add files to it, eclipse doesn't seem to auto-generate a makefile for that directory so any files I add to it are not seen by files in the default src folder.  Does eclipse only support the auto-generation for files added to the default src folder?

Comment: I would suggest to code the `Makefile` by hand. Read http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html

Comment: Yes I will definitely do that.  Part of the reason I wanted to try out eclipse's auto-generated makefile was to see what was generated when various files and directories were added to use as a starting point to learn how to write my own makefiles.

Comment: I guess that Eclipse would generate much more complex `Makefile`-s than what you need or will code at first. So they might not be a good starting point.